# For which $k$ with $0<k<210637$ is $k\times 3571\# \pm 1$ a twin-prime-pair?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes, primorial

Because PARI/GP is not very fast in primilaty testing, I did not check the
pairs $k \times 3571\# \pm 1$ in ascending order, but I begun with $k=200,000$
and got the twin prime pair

$$210637\times 3571\# \pm 1$$

- Is there a $k$ with $0<k<210637$, such that $k\times 3571 \# \pm 1$ is a twin prime pair ?

I tried to sieve out small factors, but it turned out that many candidates
remain because no member of any pair can have a prime factor $\le 3517$.

- Can I speed up the search with PARI/GP by using some clever sieving methods ?

Comment: I know the ispseudoprime-command, but checking the $200,000$ pairs takes still a very long time. And I also used the "trick" to first check the smaller member, and only if it is prime, to check the larger member instead of using the "and"-option.  It does not take long to check one number of such a magintude ($1526$ digits), but too many necessary tests remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about PARI/GP, but NewPGen can sieve pretty fast.
Running the interval $0<k<200000$ for one minute eliminated about 170000 candidates.

https://primes.utm.edu/programs/NewPGen/

@Edit: I could have perhaps explained the programm a bit. It only sieves, for testing you need another program. Pfgw performs probable prime tests, and best thing is, it can use the files created by NewPGen.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/openpfgw/

Comment: Does the program test the primality, or only sieve out small factors ? There is a button for primality tests, but I am not sure, if the program acesses the internet, if I demand primality tests.

Comment: The program seems to use $7z$-files. I recently downloaded such files, but could not unzip them. It would be nice to have a zip.-version.

Answer (score 1):

It's not NewPGen with nice sieving of these forms, but using the simple `is_prime($n-1) && is_prime($n+1)` method took [Perl/ntheory](https://metacpan.org/pod/ntheory) 20 minutes on my laptop to find k=45593, 9 minutes more for k=65996, 47 seconds more for k=67724, ...

In all, 1.5 hours for the whole range to get:

```
45593, 65996, 67724, 120451, 127964, 210637
```

The NewPGen executables don't work on my Macbook, and 282 doesn't compile.  Anyone know of something newer than 282 or fixes for 64-bit (it's trying to store a pointer in a int)?

Ideas for sieving $k * n\# \pm a$ would be nice to see.

Comment: Reliable as always :)  Thank you very much! I also downloaded proth (Searching proth primes). The program is really fast, but crashes, if numbers of about $10,000$ digits are involved. Unfortunately, I did not find a similar program checking arbitary numbers, being free of such limitations.

Comment: And I downloaded prime95, but this program is even more specialized. It seems to be limited to Mersenne-numbers, or at least very similar forms. In addition, the idea of this program is to assign works to computers on the net.

Comment: By the way, does anyone know, what happened to this site : http://factordb.com/search.php ? Since about 2 days, I could not connect to this server. It would be sad, if the server would have been removed.

Comment: factordb is having database issues right now.  There's a thread on mersennewiki about it.  prime95 is many things, mostly concentrating on Mersenne primes.  It is also a workhorse for the gwnum library.  I have code for Proth and LLR form in my software using GMP, but it of course wouldn't be as specialized as the dedicated programs (some also are more flexible, e.g. +a rather than +1).